# Use Case statement with ON clause in SQL query

Tags: sql

Need your help to fix below issue. I am using below query to get the details.

Whenever `lob` is in `lob1` and `lob2`, I want to join on ID column else want to use "No" column to join.

```sql
 SELECT a.column1,b.column1
 FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN table2 b
 ON a.region=b.region
 AND CASE WHEN a.lob IN ('lob1','lob2') 
 THEN a.id=b.id ELSE a.no=b.no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for UNION ALL and have these two as two separate SELECT clauses, as given below:

```sql
SELECT a.column1,b.column1
 FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN table2 b
 ON a.region=b.region
 AND a.id=b.id 
WHERE a.lob IN ('lob1','lob2')
UNION ALL
SELECT a.column1,b.column1
 FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN table2 b
 ON a.region=b.region
 AND a.no=b.no
 WHERE a.lob NOT IN ('lob1','lob2')
```